# EF Core bulk insert error with nullable double

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1, efcore.bulkextensions

I'm developing an application (.Net Core 3.1, C# 8) that is using Entity Framework Core and the `EFCore.BulkExtensions` NuGet package to manage bulk queries. The project is database first. The columns in the table are floats and null is allowed in the database, so it's mapped to `double?`.

I have a table with 6 `float` columns, that are mapped to 6 `nullable double` properties. My logic can generate 2 kinds of outputs: (1) when it generates a proper `double` value like `3.14` and (2) when the result is `null`.

I'm getting the following error message when I'm using the `BulkInsert()` method:

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'OLE DB provider 'STREAM' for
> linked server '(null)' returned invalid data for column
> '[!BulkInsert].CUSTOMER_SCORES'.'

Comment: Looks like related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23229862/weird-ole-db-provider-stream-for-linked-server-null-returned-invalid-data
If you still facing problems, better to create issue on library's site. Or find better bulk extension.

Comment: I walked through this thread, and I haven't find the solution there.

Comment: I would suggest to try this extension https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore and try `context.BulkCopy` with overloads and tweaking options.